# matlab fminunc not quitting (running indefinitely)

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, regression

I have been trying to implement logistic regression in matlab for a while now. I have done it  already, but for reasions unknown to me, I am unable to perform a single iteration using fminunc. When the function it called, the program just go in to wait mode indefinitely. Is there something wrong with code, or is my data set to large?

```
function [theta J] = logisticReg(initial_theta, X, y, lambda, iter)

% Set Options
options = optimset('GradObj', 'on', 'MaxIter', iter);

% Optimize
[theta, J, exit_flag] = fminunc(@(t)(costFunctionReg(t, X, y, lambda)), initial_theta, options);

end
```

where

```
X is a [676,6251] matrix
y is a [676,1] vector
lambda = 1
initial_theta is [6251, 1] vector of zeros
iter = 1
```

Any 'pointing in the right direction' will be greatly appreciated!
P.S. and I was able to run costFunctionReg. So am assuming it is this function.

as requested the costFunctionReg

```
function [J, grad] = costFunctionReg(theta, X, y, lambda)

m = length(y); % number of training examples

J = 0;
grad = zeros(size(theta));

hyp = sigmoid(X * theta);
cost_reg = (lambda / (2*m)) * sum(theta(2:end).^2);

J = 1/m * sum((-y .* log(hyp)) - ((1-y) .* log(1-hyp))) + cost_reg;


grad(1) = 1/m * sum((hyp - y)' * X(:,1));
grad(2:end) = (1/m * ((hyp - y)' * X(:,2:end))) + (lambda/m)*theta(2:end)';
```

to answer @Rasman question:

```
Cost at initial theta: NaN
press any key to continue 
Performing Logistic Regrestion
Error using sfminbx (line 28)
Objective function is undefined at initial point. fminunc cannot continue.

Error in fminunc (line 406)
   [x,FVAL,~,EXITFLAG,OUTPUT,GRAD,HESSIAN] = sfminbx(funfcn,x,l,u, ...

Error in logisticReg (line 8)
[theta, J, exit_flag] = fminunc(@(t)(costFunctionReg(t, X, y, lambda)),
initial_theta, options);

Error in main (line 40)
[theta J] = logisticReg(initial_theta, X, y, lambda, iter);
```

The first line is me running costFunctionReg with initial_theta.

Comment: can you show `costFunctionReg` - quite likely the problem is with that. Also maybe set `MaxFunEvals`- maybe you need so many calculations per iteration.

Comment: I suggest you start your code in the debugger and put a break point in the cost function to see whether you reach it and, if yes, what goes on in it.

Comment: hey, quick question. Am still new to machine learning. I am actually trying to solve a classification problem. Is that a possible reason for my problem?

Comment: Add `options= optimset(options ,'Display', 'iter-detailed');` to your options, and tell me what you see

Comment: @Rasman same thing. It says 'logistic regression started' (a print I have just before logisticReg is called), and then going into 'wait mode'.

Comment: what does sigmoid do? Have you tried different starting points?

Comment: sigmoid is a simple function that returns g = 1 ./(1+exp(-z))... and as for the different starting points i tried and I got the new print out in my post.

Comment: just double checking: It's is not because am trying to solve a classification problem, with logistic regression?

Comment: I'm not familiar with classification problems, but if certain value cause problems, you shouldn't be using fminunc. Also, the large size of the desired solution may prevent you from being able to use this numerical method: although it will run, it just may never converge properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that you already tried searching this link:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/290418

The general arc (I've copied and pasted/made edits to the text from the above site) is:

The error message indicates that your objective function "obj" either 
errors, or returns and invalid value such as Inf, NaN or a complex 
number when evaluated at the point x0.

You may want to evaluate your function at x0 before calling fmincon (or in your case, fminunc) to see if it's well defined: something like

```
  costFunctionReg(initial_theta)
```

And if your function (costFunctionReg) is returning a complex-valued result, then use real() to strip it away.