# Matlab fminunc(): implement logistic regression would use up to 99% of CPU and cause machine frozen

Tags: python, matlab, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I used fminunc() to solve a relatively large(30k X 16k as training data) machine learning problem in logistic regression approach, but every time I ran fminunc(), it immediately eat up my RAM and taking 99% of CPU for hours and my laptop was completely frozen. (I have actually 8 G RAM installed)

There might be a similar question out there: [MATLAB fminunc() not completing for large datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696459/matlab-fminunc-not-completing-for-large-datasets-works-for-smaller-ones)  , but it is essentially different from my case in points below:

- I followed his conclusive idea, setting 'LargeScale' to 'Off', but
  that, unfortunately, didn't work for my case. Setting 'LargeScale' to
  be 'On' or 'Off' would result in the same situation - running
  fminunc() caused my machine paralyzed
- My dataset has more examples than features ( 32k X 16k)
- I am using Sparse matrix instead of full as the input training set X

My Cost function is as follows:

```
function [J, grad] = costFunction(theta, X, y)

[m, n] = size(X);

J = 1/m*sum( (-y).*log(sigmoid(X*theta)) - (1-y).*log(1-sigmoid(X*theta)) );

grad = 1/m*( X' * (sigmoid(X*theta)- y) );

end
```

My pre-processing steps and fminunc() function are as follows:

```
...
% some script to preprocess data and create sparse matrix X as input ( X is 32769 * 16601 and 
% containing only 0s or 1s); and y is the target column vector, containing only 0s or 1s; and initial_theta is a column 
% vector of 0s
...

options = optimset('GradObj', 'on', 'MaxIter', 400);

[theta, cost] = fminunc(@(t)(costFunction(t, X, y)), initial_theta, options);
```

and sigmoid function:

```
function g = sigmoid(z)

g = zeros(size(z));

g = exp(-z) + 1;

g = 1./g;

end
```

The dataset is from one of the data science competitions from [kaggle: *Amazon.com - Employee Access Challenge*](http://www.kaggle.com/c/amazon-employee-access-challenge), and I have preprocessed the original training data by using One Hot Encoding (the features are categorical), and the features expanded from 8 to 16600, so the training data X is sparse matrix of dimension 32769 * 16601 (added one column vector of 1s)

I am new to machine learning and also a Coursera user. I took Prof Andrew Ng's machine learning course so I implemented based on his taught method. I am just wondering if anyone could advise why my fminunc() is so slow for this case and extremely CPU-consuming.

```
8G RAM, 2.5GHz, Matlab R2014a
```

I also separately tested my cost function itself with the same dataset X, y and initial_theta, and one execution time for the cost function itself is between 0.002 to 0.02 seconds:

```
tic
[cost, grad] = costFunction(initial_theta, X, y)
Toc
```

**I used the same training data (the sparse matrix X) into python's Logistic Regression classifier: model = linear_model.LogisticRegression, and the process time took only one second!**

so,

1. is fminunc not good for such case?
2. does my cost function need to be improved?
3. any parameters not set properly?

Appreciate any advice!

Thanks,

Weimin